# Inherit Group Category From Other Module's security.xml in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo

hope you are well today.

I have two `security.xml` files inside two custom different modules. One module is called `picking_rename` and another one is `so_rename`.

In the `picking_rename` module, i made a group category and the group itself. It shown like this one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <!-- The group Category -->
    <record model ="ir.module.category" id="rename_privileges">
        <field name="name">Rename Privilege</field>
        <field name="description">Renaming privilege for certain documents</field>
    </record>

    <!-- The group -->
    <record id ="rename_picking_true" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Rename Partner Picking Order</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="rename_privileges" />
    </record>
</odoo>
```

In my other `security.xml` inside `so_rename`, I also made a group. I want to make this group under the `rename_privileges`, which is declared in the different module as i said above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <!-- The group -->
    <record id ="rename_so_true" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Rename Customer in Sales Order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="picking_rename.rename_privileges"/>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

I already put the `picking_rename` module inside `depends` in my `so_rename`, but i still got the error message.

```
    'depends': [
        'stock',
        'sale_management',
        'picking_rename'
    ],
```

The error message is shown below

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pramardhika/Desktop/odoo15/odoo/http.py", line 644, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/Users/pramardhika/Desktop/odoo15/odoo/http.py", line 302, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /Users/pramardhika/Desktop/odoo15/custom/odooapps/so_rename/security/security.xml:8, somewhere inside
<record id="rename_so_true" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Rename Sales Order</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="rename_privileges"/>
    </record>
```

How can i make inheritance happen?
Appreciate for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh i solved it now,

I just need to add `ref=moduleName.groupName` in the field. It's because the `category_id` is already installed along with the first module, so i just need to "normally call" it.

My code in `security.xml` inside `so_rename` module become like this :

```
    <record model="res.groups" id ="rename_so_true">
        <field name="name">Rename Sales Order</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="picking_rename.rename_privileges" />
    </record>
```

Both group is now "united" under one category group as expected.
[image]